# jQuery ajax function undefined result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I realize this is asked a lot and usually the answer is that AJAX is asynchronous and this is why it's returning undefined, but even though I set my async to false here, it's still returning undefined when the function is called. res is always undefined

```
function sendRequest(link, type, query) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            'url' : link,
            'type' : type,
            'data' : query,
            'async' : false,
            'dataType': "json",
            'headers': {
                'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
                'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6',
            }, 
            'success': function(data) {
                var res = data;
            }
        });
    });
    return res;
}
```

Also I am sure that the request is being sent correctly and that the response is received correctly as well

Comment: 1) Don't use `async: false`. Bad. 2) The `var` scopes the variable to the callback function so it isn't accessible outside that function.

Comment: In "var res" var define the scope, res  doesn´t exist out from function called from success

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to declare and assign `res` separately.

```
var res;

$.ajax({
    // ...
    'success': function (data) {
        res = data;
    }
});

return res;
```

Currently, `res` is being declared as a local variable solely inside the `success` callback. So, it won't be accessible to the rest of `sendRequest()`.

---

Though, you should try to avoid using `async: false` with Ajax.

You can instead `return` the `Deferred` jqXHR provided by `$.ajax()`, allowing the calling function to add its own handler.

```
function sendRequest(link, type, query) {
    return $.ajax({
        // ...
    });
}

sendRequest(...).done(function (data) {
    // ...
});
```

More details and options are described in "[How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)"

Comment: Even after fixing the scope, it's still returning undefined.

Comment: @Ali With the snippet I suggested, `res` will only be assigned on `success`. Is the request `error`ing instead?

Comment: No. It's running perfectly. It's receiving the response too. I check that using an HTTP Request monitor

Comment: @Ali The request can still `error` when jQuery attempts to parse the response, despite a `200` status. Is the response, in its entirety, a single, [valid](http://jsonlint.com/) JSON value?

Answer (score 2):

I think a better approach would be to have your `sendRequest` function return a [jQuery Promise Object](http://api.jquery.com/promise/). As an example

```
function sendRequest(link, type, query) {
  return $.ajax({
        'url' : link,
        'type' : type,
        'data' : query,
        'dataType': "json",
        'headers': {
            'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
            'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6',
        }
    });
}
```

To use

```
sendRequest('/someurl', 'GET', {}).done(function(data) {
  // do whatever you need with data here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** `res` should be outside ajax scope, and **Secondly**  function will return before ajax call completes thats the reason its undefined:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            'url' : link,
            'type' : type,
            'data' : query,
            'async' : false,
            'dataType': "json",
            'headers': {
                'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
                'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6',
            }, 
            'success': function(data) {
                MyFunction(data);
            }
        });


function MyFunction(data)
{

// do with ajax resonse what is needed
}
```

Comment: the function doesn't return until the ajax is complete because of: `'async' : false`

Comment: async should not be set false, it suspends the UI and make it worse as ajax call is send via UI thread

Answer (score 0):

It's a scope problem.
You need to declare `var res;` in a scope that's accessible to the return, and just update that object inside of the AJAX.

```
function sendRequest(link, type, query) {
    var res;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            //...
            'success': function(data) {
                res = data;
            }
        });
    });
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is async (at least it should be, I would refrain from using `async` set to `false`), so the result will be undefined. Use a callback:

```
function sendRequest(link, type, query, callback) {
    $.ajax({
       ..
       ..
       'success': function(data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}

sendRequest(link, type, query, function(data) {
    console.log(data); //YOUR DATA
});
```

Comment: he set async to false.